# how to refresh the root view after dismissal of a modal view?

Tags: iphone

After presenting another view on my rootview, then I dismiss it, I want to refresh or reload my view, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Send the view `setNeedsDisplay` message.

Answer (score 0):

I define a simple protocol for modal view controllers to use to notify their parent that they're done:

```
@protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)modalViewControllerDone:(UIViewController*)viewController;
@end
```

The parent then implements this protocol, and assigns itself to the modal view controller's `delegate` property.  When the modal view controller is finished, it calls `[delegate modalViewControllerDone:self]`.  The parent then dismisses the modal view controller and can do whatever else it wants (in your case, reload something).